# How do I get SAM to perform multi-class classification?

Tags: multiclass-classification, image-segmentation

I want to use the Segment Anything Model(SAM) to perform multi-class segmentation on satellite images. When I tried to apply it, it ended up giving single-class outputs. Moreover, upon applying a SoftMax activation layer, I got the warning, "UserWarning: single channel prediction, softmax=True ignored.
warnings.warn("single channel prediction, softmax=True ignored.")". How do I get SAM to perform multi-class classification?